# AddOrUpdate - usar array como parâmetro

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, parâmetros

Estou realizando testes com Entity Framework e tive um problema ao colocar um *array* como parâmetro.

1. Por que quando atribuo a conversão do *array* em uma variável funciona e diretamente no parâmetro do método não funciona?
2. Esse comportamento é normal?
3. Se sim, qual nome?

## Funciona

```
List<Product> product = new List<Product>()
var p = product.ToArray();
db.Product.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, p);
```

## Não funciona

```
List<Product> product = new List<Product>()
db.Product.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, product.ToArray());
```

Comment: Não funciona como? Certamente não é por causa de faltar um `)` em `db.Product.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, product.ToArray();` ou é?

Comment: Não é por isso. Quando é convertido no parâmetro ele apenas não insere, não dá erro algum.

Comment: Você tem como explicar como essa variável `product` é formada?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez editei a pergunta.

Comment: Mas não precisa converter pra array pra usar o `AddOrUpdate`. E a lista está vazia. Isto está correto?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez a lista vem através de um Post, coloquei só para identificar que é uma lista de objetos. O AddOrUpdate espera um array do tipo Product (params Product[]).

Answer (score 1):

Isso é porque LINQ to Entities requer que toda a expressão do LINQ seja traduzido para uma consulta de servidor e, portanto, você não pode chamar um método de fora, no seu caso o linq não reorganiza os dados dentro de seus métodos, ou seja não tem como converte seu product para array `product.ToArray()` dentro do método `AddOrUpdate` esse método espera um array e não um objeto que chama o método `ToArray()` e retorne um array.

Para que isso funcione, você terá que reestruturar a sua expressão de consulta em uma expressão que [Entity Framework pode manipular](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&u=http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2009/05/28/entity-sql-user-defined-functions-in-entity-framework-4/&usg=ALkJrhibVYm9GAiBpUcYiBeNNHbqXkauqg).

Comment: Como você pode ver em [`DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbsetmigrationsextensions.addorupdate(v=vs.113).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2), o terceiro parametro deste método é `params TEntity[] entities`, por não ser uma `Expression` não sofre nenhum tipo de tradução para SQL por parte do `EF`.

Comment: [`DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate - Source`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbSetMigrationsExtensions.cs#L78)

Comment: o método AddOrUpdate espera um array e não um objeto que chama o método ToArray() e retorne um array. O ef não sabe fazer isso.